How to read the content of the Smart Contract?
Suppose below is my Solidity code
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract HelloWorld {
string public greeting = "HELLO WORLD";
}

Now when after I deploy it on the Sepolia testnet, how can I see the exact contents of the smart contract, especially the string "Hello World".
All I can see on the Sepolia Etherscan is the bytecode and opcodes, and even after decoding them, i get to see the disassembled low-level code, but can NOT retrieve the original solidity code.
Is it possible to retrieve "Hello World" from the available Deployment Tx. Hash?

If you want to view your contract code and interact with it directly on a block explorer like Sepolia Etherscan, you need to verify your contract first.
To verify the contract on Remix IDE, refer to this answer.
